# Find largest regions bounded by a set of planes

Tags: volume, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose we are given a set of planes that partition the unit cube into a large number of regions. Is there a computationally efficient way to find the region with the largest volume?

Comment: Monte-Carlo maybe? No idea how efficient it is but 1. Generate N points uniformly inside the cube. 2. Each of the n planes will give 2n region constraints of the form $ax+by+cz\le{d}$ and $ax+by+cz\ge{d}$. 3. Each volume will be the intersection of n of these regions ($2^n$ possibilities and many of which will have zero volume as the combinations of $\le$ and $\ge$ give an empty set). Count how many of each of the N points land in each region. If N is large then the region with the highest point count wins. The $2^n$ inequality combinations is a worry though.

Comment: I am fairly certain the answer is *No*. This bald claim is not useful to you, I know. One could ask the easier question in 2D: the largest-area cell in an arrangement of lines. I think the complexity is $\Omega(n^d)$ in dimension $d$. But I am not finding a difinitive reference...